# Exit from function after resolving protractor promise

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am fairly new to JavaScript and Protractor. I have simple task in my test that I am unable to complete.

1. Check on available Tab on web page.
2. Check if element is visible on web page.
3. a) If Yes, `return deffered.fullfil(true)`
   b) If No,
         - Click on In-Progress Tab 
         - Click on Available Tab.
         - Go to Step 1.

I am trying to do this recursively and below is my code. It is printing Element found but never exits the function after that and times out.

```
var check_availability = function(counter, totalCount, element){
var deferred = potractor.promise.defer()
if(counter <= totalCount){
    browser.wait(function(){
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element),2000)
        return element
    }).then(function(success){
        console.log('Element found.')
        return deferred.fulfill(true)
    }, function(err){
       inprogressTab.click()
       .then(() => availableTab .click())
       .then(() => check_availability (counter+1 , totalCount, element))
    })
   } else{
   return deferred.reject(false)
  }
  return deferred.promise
}
```

PS: This is a sample code that I am using, corrected some spelling mistakes and syntax.

Comment: When you provide code (which is good), at least make sure it can be run. It has several spelling mistakes, so it cannot even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several syntax errors on your shared code. Below i tried to fix those errors and provided the expected behavior but still don't know from where the `inprogressTab` is coming from.

```
const check_availibility = function(counter, totalCount, element) {
  const deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    if (counter <= totalCount) {
       browser
        .wait(() => browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 2000))
   .then(
    element => {
      console.log("Element found.");
      return deferred.fulfill(true);
    },
    err => {
      inprogressTab
        .click()
        .then(() => availableTab.click())
        .then(() => check_availibility(counter + 1, totalCount, element));
    }
  );
} else {
   return deferred.reject(false);
}
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me and apologies for spellings mistakes and syntax errors, It was just a  sample code I had to type in to demonstrate my approach.

Comment: Please note that this code still uses the promise constructor antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

First, this code has spelling mistakes. "deferred" is with one "f", and so the call `promise.deffer()` will give a runtime error. It should be `.defer()`. Also `rpotractor` is misspelled. Your code could not even run.

Secondly, you are using an anitpattern: there is no need to create a promise/deferred, when you already get a promise object from `browser.wait`. Just return that one (or one returned from a `then` chain).

Also, `return element` is a wrong return value. It executes synchronously, so before the waiting is over, and the `then` chain will kick in too soon. Instead, make sure to *return* the promise that `browser.wait` returns.

You could do something like this:

```
var check_availibility = function(counter, totalCount, element){
    if (counter <= totalCount) {
        return browser.wait(function () {
            return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 2000)
//          ^^^^^^
        }).then(function () {
            console.log('Element found.')
            return true;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return inprogressTab.click()
//          ^^^^^^
                .then(() => availableTab.click())
                .then(() => check_availibility(counter+1 , totalCount, element))
        })
    } else {
        return protractor.promise.rejected(false);
    }
}
```

Note that JavaScript has native Promise support since EcmaScript2015, so instead of using `protractor.promise`, you could just use `Promise`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I'll definitely try this approach and apologies for spellings mistakes and syntax errors, It was just a sample code I had to type in to demonstrate my approach.